# Make a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I've this website I made in html/css. And I'm just starting to learn RubyOnRails and I'd like to turn my URL links into controllers. So I made a new controller, and now I don't know how to go forward. I got an email button which I made a controller for mail_controller.rb and want it to link to my email adress.

Comment: Was one of the answers below valid?

Answer (score 1):

You need not only the controller, but also the routes for that.
Make sure you have on the `config/routes.rb` file a route mapping the url you want with the controller you made.

Perhaps you may want to take a look at the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to link your email, you don't necessarily need a controller for that. You can just do:

```
link_to 'Click to email me', 'mailto: me@example.com'
```

and it will open the user's mail client to sent a mail to the given email address. If you wanted to use action mailer, then I suggest you read:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem like you are just starting with Rails. I would highly recommend that you get a book to start with that. Agile Rails is probably a very good choice for newcomers in Rails.

It will help you better understand how the MVC model works in Rails, how to set up controllers, models, routes and more. At this point when you start, you need to have a better understand of how Rails works overall and the best way to do that is by reading a book or, maybe even better, do as Sebastian Martinez says, read the online guides.